# How to Display Count beside a category in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can we display #of items in a category displayed in a particular UITableViewCell?
 For example, in iPhone mail app, they show # of new emails in each account..

Thanks
Jignesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply customize your `UITableViewCell` ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18)) and add a custom `UILabel` as a subview of your cell so it displays on the right.

If you want to make this UILabel to look like the ones in Mail, this is quite simple, as you may try sthg like this:

```
countLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140,10,60,24)] autorelease];
countLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
countLabel.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
countLabel.layer.cornerRadius = countLabel.bounds.size.height / 2;
countLabel.masksToBounds = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:countLabel];

countLabel.text = [categoryItems count];
```

*(Note: to use the layer property of UILabel, don't forget to add the QuartzCore framework and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`)*

Comment: Thank You very much AliSoftware!!! I saved lot of my time as i thought it was an accessorytype...

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`TDBadgeCell`](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell) library on Github.

[image]

Comment: This is good one too !!! Since I have very simple requirements, I just created with simple code shown by @AliSoftware. Thanks anyway!!!